# Get Airflow REST API url from DAG

Tags: python, airflow

Let's say I want a DAG which send a email to someone with the specific URL needed to contact it's REST API (my airflow is not on localhost, then accessible from the web). I would then need to have access to this URL from a DAG instance. Is there a template for this? Or another way?

For example I need to guess the `host` in this API url:

```
   https://{host}/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/
```

```
 send_email_task = EmailOperator(
            task_id="send_email",
            to=RECIPIENT,
            subject=SUBJECT,
            html_content=f"""<body>You can trigger my dag using: https://{host}/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/</body>"""
        )
```

Comment: You want a Directed Acyclic Graph to send emails?

Comment: Yes but its not the matter. I want to get the host url from a Directed Acyclic Graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow tasks are running on scheduler and workers services which are completely independent from the Airflow webserver, and you can create an Airflow server without a webserver, and it can work without any problem, and you can manage the tasks/dags using Airflow CLI. Airflow webserver host is a DNS name, and it doesn't have any relation with Airflow

In order to access this DNS name from you dags, you can create a variable in the metadata, and access it from you dags.

Here is the [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html) which explain how to create and access Airflow variables. If you have multiple environment (Dev, QA, Prod) servers with different URL, you can create the same variable in all the environments with different value for each one, and your dag will be able to use the correct url.